# How to retrieve all minimum edge cut sets in Networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I am using python library networkx  and looking for way to find all minimum edge cut sets of given graph.
Let say that I have undirected graph **G**, which has edge connectivity 2.
I want to find its all possible minimum edge cut sets, i.e. all two cuts that disconnects **G**.
Let say that in **G** I have nodes on one hand *A* and *B* connected to *C* and on another hand *D* and *E* connected to *F*. This function:

`nx.minimum_edge_cut(G)`

returns one such set, let say: {(A, C), (B, C)}. But it is possible that this function will return {(D, F), (E, F)}.

One solution that I was considering was to removing by hand nodes which are outliers, but my actual graph is way bigger than this and I don't want to change my graph for further analysis.